# Point in array of polygons, if true get name of polygon mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, polygon, geojson, point

in my polygons collection I have many kinds of polygons, let's say type A, B and C.
Also, I have a points collection where I have stored last lat,lng of those points. What I want, is to know if that last position of points are inside a polygons and if its true, bring the type of the polygon where my point is.

My points collection documents looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "KYBV21",
  "lat": -33.389222,
  "lng": -70.692958,
  "date_time": "2020-06-22 17:00:55",
  "cod_plate": "KYBV21"
}
```

My polygons collection looks like this:

```
{
  "geoJson": {
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            -106.134222,
            28.72389
          ],
          [
            -106.134222,
            28.725734
          ],
          [
            -106.131669,
            28.725734
          ],
          [
            -106.131669,
            28.72389
          ],
          [
            -106.134222,
            28.72389
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "zone_type": "origin"
}
```

I have tried bringing both separately, but it takes longer than I expected. So I want to know if there is another solution doing both queries in just one.